# How can I get an lower-case "L" with a hooked tail

Tags: math-mode, bold

I'm marking up some text that includes "l" as a vector, so I'd like to be able to use a bold font. `\mathbf{l}` gives a straight up-and-down kind of l which looks like a 1 (one) or an I (capital "i"):

[image]

I don't want to use `\ell` because I don't want the loop and for some reason my system won't make the corresponding glyph bold for me.

What I'd like looks more like this:

[image]

What are my options?

Comment: As regards the second reason for not using the symbol `\ell`, with `amsmath`, `\boldsymbol\ell` gives a bold `\ell` with the curly tail.

Comment: @AndrewSwann I don't believe that this _question_ is a duplicate: the answer you link to may well solve the problem, but the _specific_ question isn't trivial and searching the site before asking didn't lead me to the question you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Ah - thanks to @Andrew Swann for his comment which led me to the correct answer. I was using `\mathbf{l}` when I should have been using `\boldsymbol{l}`.